# What makes up the number shown on my 'like' button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, social-networking

I have a question regarding the Facebook ‘like’ button.

I have a blog which I have updated regularly for the past two years. At the bottom of each post there is a Facebook ‘like’ button, which visitors can choose to click. If they do so, this click registers as a ‘like’. However, when I paste the URL into my Facebook status update, the number of shares/ likes and comments about this URL do not register on the ‘like’ button on my blog. In the past these actions did feed through as ‘likes’ on my page, but now it appears the only way to ‘like’ my post is to go to the blog page itself and ‘like the post’.

I read the ‘Facebook Developers’ page about the like button, and it says-

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

“What makes up the number shown on my Like button?
The number shown is the sum of:
•   The number of likes of this URL 
•   The number of shares of this URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook) 
•   The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL 
•   The number of inbox messages containing this URL as an attachment.”

Can you tell me why this is happening- has something on Facebook changed recently?
Many thanks,
Katy

Comment: Recently I've seen questions about why counts are 0 for blog entries. I'm wondering if this issue is associated with a particular blog engine.  What engine do you use?

Answer (score 0):

When you post a link to a URL, you are essentially creating a new [post object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) that has a separate number of likes and comments.
What you want to do is share your link as you have mentioned - and add the text -

> Please enter the blog and click the like button!

Comment: @DMCSI have a Weebly blog. I've read various posts on the issue in forums etc and most people with a similar query seemed to use Wordpress, so I don't think it's a problem specific to Weebly. V. frustrating, esp when it used to register all likes, shares, comments etc as 'likes'.

Answer (score 0):

Researching the facebook "like situation" some people have suggested the following can add up to the # of likes: (ref http://www.blogdefined.com/9037/facebook-share-count/)

```
Number of Facebook share by each facebook users on their wall
             + 
Number of likes received by other facebook users on each wall update
             +
Number of Comments made on each wall 
             = 
        Total Likes
```

However in my experience there is NO consistency with the Facebook like situation and Facebook needs to get their act together. I have some pages that will show 60 likes, and then those likes will disappear. I've also seen discrepancies with a trailing slash providing different results to the Facebook like algorithm even when the meta og tags are of the same url...so I wish there were consistant answers, but from what I have seen there is not.